# LoadString with numeric idetifier

Tags: winapi

i have problem with this code:

```
    int
WINAPI
Getdesc(IN WORD wcode,
         OUT LPWSTR lpBuf)
{
    WCHAR szDescription[256];
    int res = LoadStringW(NULL,wcode,szDescription,256);
    if(res == 0)
    { 

        wcscpy(lpBuf, L"Undefined");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        wcscpy(lpBuf,szDescription);
        return 0;
     }
}
```

The function is placed in a DLL, and when i access it, it always returns "Undefined",
I think there is problem in my LoadString call, but i can't figure it out.
I'm new to windows programming, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing `NULL` as the `HINSTANCE` parameter. That means that you look for the resource in the executable host and not the DLL. You'll have to pass the module handle of the DLL. You are provided with that instance handle as the first parameter passed to your [`DllMain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583.aspx) function.

If you are compiling with MSVC then you could use [`__ImageBase`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/10/25/247180.aspx) to obtain the module handle. Personally I would suggest that making a note of the value passed to `DllMain` is a cleaner approach. It avoids taking a dependency on one specific compiler.

Note also that you can call `GetLastError` in case `LoadString` fails to obtain more information about the reason for the error. It's quite possible that would have helped you identify the fault.

Comment: Thank you! at last i figured it out!

Comment: Allowing you to pass `NULL` as a shorthand for "the executable" was in retrospect a bad idea.

Comment: @Raymond NULL as shorthand for the module that the caller resides in would seem to be better.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That would require stack walking and would break tail call optimization. It would also break wrapper functions.

Comment: @RaymondChen Ah well. So I guess the current `NULL` shorthand was chosen because it was tractable. But the downside is that it's counter intuitive.